# Showing name in url instead of id?

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I am building a small app in Laravel, but I needed to use some help. I read similar tasks but I don't see them related to what I have.

The app that I'm building is a dictionary and I really don't get the part where words are displayed by **id** in the URL. I tried to revert the logic for the curds (**store, update, delete, show**) so that they perform actions using the *word name* and not the *word id*. That worked. The redirecting to route **app/{name}** after the actions does work too.

Now, I presume this is not how it needs to be done, when the curds aren't taking actions on the *id*?

I also read about slugs, but since I'm building a dictionary, don't understand why I need to separate the word by a **"-"**? It's a single word, not like posts. And why do I need to have an extra field in my form for the slug, as the **slug** must be equal to the **name**? I'm getting here an error: *the slug->unique() field must be not null*.

If somebody has the time, please explain to me what's the best way for making the **names of the words** being displayed in the URL. Thank you, I appreciate it.

**Edit**

Here is my code for the update crud:

```
public function update(UpdateWordRequest $request, $name)
{
    Word::query()->where('name', $name)->firstOrFail()->update($request->input());
    return redirect()->route('dictionary.show', ['name' => $name])->with('success', 'Edited successfully!');
}
```

It's working fine, but when I re-edit the word and change it to word2, with a number, I then get this error: **Trying to get property 'name' of non-object**.

What do I need to make of it? Thank you :)!

Comment: if all of your 'names' are always unique then there is nothing wrong with using the name as the id

Comment: They are indeed unique, but when I add for example word1 and word2, I get an error: Trying to get property of non-object.

Comment: hard to tell without code ;)

Comment: show us some code

Comment: I'll provide you with my code in a while. I'm trying to fix this error: App\Word::language must return a relationship instance. Don't know where the problem here might be. It did work some hours ago.

Comment: it should be unique, indexed, and use `::where()->first()` rather than `find`

Comment: I actually used `firstOrFail()`, with only `first()` I get the **Null** pointer error.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should be able to use a trait to fix this issue.

I would create a trait call hasSlug and have the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait HasSlug
{

protected static function bootHasSlug()
{
    static::creating(function ($model) {

        $columnName = static::getSlugColumn();

        $model->$columnName = str_slug($model->name); //convert your name to slug
    });
}


public function getSlugAttribute()
{
    $columnName = static::getSlugColumn();

    return (string) $this->attributes[$columnName];
}

protected static function getSlugColumn()
{
    if (isset(static::$slugColumn)) {
        return static::$slugColumn;
    }

    return 'slug';
}
}
```

So now if you use HasSlug trait to your model every time you create a record it will go and look for name field from your model and create a slug out of it.

Be sure to apply unique constrain to your name field if needed.

For more robust have a look at spatie slug package https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable

Comment: Okay, but what about the cruds. Do I need something like "`Word::query()->where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail()...`; or `first()` only". And again, what about the migrations. Is there a **slug string** needed which has to be **unique()**, and do I need to add a form for the slug field? Thank you!

Comment: Firstly add a migration to create slug field. No you dont have to have a slug field in the form as you can see it will take your name field and create a slug for it and yes you can do Word::query()..... or whatever

Comment: Okay, looks not that difficult. I'll give it a try in my phpstorm and see if it works. Also, I presume the variable `$model` is what ever I foreached in my show view, like `$words as $word`? Thank you!

Comment: The model is what you will use HasSlug trait. For example if you use HasSlug in Word.php then the model would be $word if something else will be something else

Comment: `Field 'slug' doesn't have a default value`. Does it need to be `nullable()` too?

Comment: did you add `use HasSlug;` trait to your model?

Comment: I did, only something is not good with my store method, so I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: I don't know if it is because of that, but do I need to return the cruds to where they performed the actions by the id. Cause the are now set to show, store, update, destroy by name. Thank you!

Comment: Wait a second are you able to create a slug and save it to the database?

Comment: No yet, cause the store function doesn't do it's job. But the trait and the model are set.

Comment: can I see your code? just send me a link to screenshot

Comment: Yep, [here](https://ibb.co/iVJmxG). Or do I need some getSlugOptions() for the store and update actions.

Comment: `Word::findBySlug($name)->firstOrFail()->create($request->input());` what exactly are you trying to do here? Do you know  what does `firstOrFail` does?

Comment: add yourself to this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162705/showing-name-in-url-instead-of-id

Comment: May be retrieving the first result of the query, if there is any. Not so sure, as I'm new to laravel. Not having the rep to chat yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I finally come up with.

**Word.php**

I used as @usrNotFound suggested [spatie/laravel-sluggable](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable).

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Spatie\Sluggable\HasSlug;
use Spatie\Sluggable\SlugOptions;

class Word extends Model
{
    use HasSlug;

    /**
    * @return SlugOptions
    */
    public function getSlugOptions(): SlugOptions
    {
        return SlugOptions::create()
            ->generateSlugsFrom('name')
            ->saveSlugsTo('slug')
            ->slugsShouldBeNoLongerThan(20);
    }

    /**
    * @param $query
    * @param $slug
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function scopeFindBySlug($query, $slug)
    {
        return $query->where('slug', $slug)
            ->get();
    }
}
```

**WordController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Word;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateWordRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateWordRequest;

class WordController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     * @param CreateWordRequest $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function store(CreateWordRequest $request)
    {
        $word = Word::query()
            ->create($request->input());
        return redirect()
            ->route('dictionary.show', $word->slug)
            ->with('success', 'Created successfully!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     * @param $slug
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function show($slug)
    {
        $word = Word::whereSlug($slug)
            ->firstOrFail();
        return view('word.show')
            ->with('word', $word);
    }

    /**
    * Update the specified resource in storage.
    * @param UpdateWordRequest $request
    * @param $slug
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function update(UpdateWordRequest $request, $slug)
    {
        Word::whereSlug($slug)
            ->firstOrFail()
            ->update($request->input());
        return redirect()
            ->route('dictionary.show', $slug)
            ->with('success', 'Edited successfylly!');
    }

    /**
    * Remove the specified resource from storage.
    * @param $slug
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function destroy($slug)
    {
        Word::whereSlug($slug)
            ->delete();
        return redirect()
            ->route('dictionary.index')
            ->with('success', 'Deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

**Route.php**

```
Route::get('/dictionary/{slug}', 'WordController@show')
    ->name('dictionary.show')
    ->where('slug', '[-A-Za-z0-9_-]+');
```

Creating, updating, destroying new words works fine. Eventually there is a small problem. When I want to update a particular word and change the name of it, after saving the word, I'm getting

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

and if I look at the url I see the old name instead of the new one. **Has this to do with my update method and how do I fix it**?